# Python logging in file

Tags: python

There is a simple way how can I write a log where it shows the custom error message

```
# importing teh module
import logging
 
try:
    printf("GeeksforGeeks")
except Exception as Argument:
 
     # creating/opening a file
     f = open("demofile2.txt", "a")
       
 
     # writing in the file
     f.write(str(Argument))
      
     # closing the file
     f.close()
```

the error comes here

> name 'printf' is not defined

though if I run this code without `try` & `Exception`:

```
printf("GeeksforGeeks")
```

the actual error jupyter showing me as

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) C:\WINDOWS\TEMP/ipykernel_21560/2330216246.py in 
> ----> 1 printf("GeeksforGeeks")
>
> NameError: name 'printf' is not defined

So I have two questions:

1. I want to write this error in my file instead of the custom one.
2. Is there any way to use it without `try:`, I have a long code and I scheduled it, however if this fails I don't know why this is actually failing. I don't want to write too many `try:` `exception:` or maintain this indent issue while writing this code.

I want when this is schedule I can get the actual reason why it failed in a log file. Please help...

Comment: There's no `printf()` in python stdlib, you probably have meant [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). Check [7. Input and Output](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#input-and-output).

Comment: In the first case you are printing the *exception*; in the second, you are seeing a *traceback*. After you catch an exception, you call `sys.exc_info` to get back (among other things) an associated `traceback` object.

Comment: printf is there because that will generate an error. Can you give an example of how sys.exc_info will work exactly.